# Getting output parameter from stored procedure to php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hello so far this is end of my sql based knowledge, i am seeking some help. As you can see this is my stored procedure. I only want get that TestPkId to php.[image: This is storred procedure]
and this is php which is sending some data where produced on my html it send data to database which is procedure use.

```
$PersonName=$_GET['PersonName'];
$TestXML=$_GET['TestXML'];
$TestDate=$_GET['TestDate'];
include('DBConnect.php');
    $proc = "{call p_set_Test(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";   
    $params = array($TestDate,0,$PersonName,$TestXML,'',101,10,0);   
    $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $proc, $params);
// how to get testpkid into php parametr in this php?
```

if it isn't understandable i will try to explain more thank you

Comment: Try to pass a variable like $TestPkID (which is set to 0) in the $params instead of 0

Comment: @Sujith thanks but thats no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$PersonName=$_GET['PersonName'];
$TestXML=$_GET['TestXML'];
$TestDate=$_GET['TestDate'];
include('DBConnect.php');
    $proc = "{call p_set_Test(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";   
    $params = array($TestDate,0,$PersonName,$TestXML,'',101,10,0);   
    $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $proc, $params);
```

i get all variable from this php and put it to html simple and answered